# java.rmi.MarshalException: Failed to communicate

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, jboss-tools

I'm using jbossIDE Eclipse 1.6. when deploying my .ear app, I get a java.rmi.MarshalException.

what's surprising is that just a few min ago, everything was OK.

I feel like this jbossIDE Eclipse thing is really useless. it's crashing all the time.

```
    java.rmi.MarshalException: Failed to communicate.  Problem during
              marshalling/unmarshalling; nested exception is: 
java.io.InvalidClassException: com.afrikbrain.util.message.MessageInfo; local class 
    incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 2285009932770474121, local class 
    serialVersionUID = -2900394430145132451

    at   
 org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.SocketClientInvoker.handleException(SocketClientInvoker.java:122)
at 

 org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.MicroSocketClientInvoker.transport(MicroSocketClientInvoker.java:644)
at 
 org.jboss.remoting.MicroRemoteClientInvoker.invoke(MicroRemoteClientInvoker.java:122)
```

Comment: and note nothing of this and the 3 other questions you posted has anything to do with JBossIDE which btw. is 3 years old by now - considered upgrading to JBoss Tools ? :)

Answer (score 1):

The version of the class `com.afrikbrain.util.message.MessageInfo` that is deployed to your EJB server is different from the one in your client.  That is why they have different serial IDs.  Try removing and re-compiling everything so that you have exactly the same version of the class deployed on both the server and client.